# Url Shortener redirects to index.html

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jetty, stack-overflow

Yes, yet another url shortener written in java, because I wanted my own, and because why not.  Currently everything works, just not they way I want to to.  In short, there is only one servlet mapped to "/" in the entire project.  There are no frameworks involved, or anything fancy, this is just a basic Servlet "project".  on doPost a new shortUrl is created, and you get a JSON response.  On doGet, if the URL is "/*{any_valid_short_url}" then a redirect is sent (below).

```
response.sendRedirect("longUrlString")
```

The issue I am having is with the index page, when the same doGet is called, I check the requested path, if it is "/" then currently, I use a FileInputStream and stream the index.html page out via response.getOutputStream(), which is pretty hacky in my opinion.  I would like to use a requestDispatcher instead, however when I do try to implement that (below) I get into a re-direct loop, and the servlet container (jetty or tomcat) stack overflow's.

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(req, res);
```

Is there something that I am mis-understanding about how this is being done?  The project is currently hosted on my github page.  https://github.com/justinmburrous/ShortUrl

Comment: What is getServletContext() returning? You should be using `req.getRequestDispatchter(...)`

Comment: Oops...  but still the same issue, stack overflow, caused by a massive amount of re-directs.

Comment: Please, post the code where you get the RequestDispatcher.

Comment: Sure, so I have updated and commented what is working (but hacky), and the new request dispatcher attempt.  I have tried multiple variations of index.html /index.html, and checked it's location.  I have also tried welcome file, however with a catch all servlet like this that has issue.  https://github.com/justinmburrous/ShortUrl/blob/request_dispatcher/src/com/jmb/shorturl/servlets/RedirectorServlet.java

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this check more narrower, because for all requests this  condition is true and hence for all requests are  forwarded to 'index.html' again and again

```
    if(requestedPath.equals("/")){

    //tried with multiple variations of /index.html, renamed to jsp, etc...
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);    
    }
```

**Edit:**
Since your servlet is mapped as default servlet , all forwards or request will be handled by this Servlet.
You should map the url to more specific range.

[RequestDispatcher - forward - produces infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934909/how-to-let-servlet-mapping-to)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying.  Currently (this is on the master branch without the RequestDispatcher) if you request http://jburr.co/ you get the index page (via the hacky output stream), however if you request jburr.co/c you get cnn.com, a test page I just added.  So the if() that checks the requested path is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured this one out with thanks to **[How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513)**

My github page has the working code along with the Filter, modified servlet and web.xml for.